# QR Code calendar event with relative dates

Tags: qr-code, icalendar, vcalendar

I am looking for a QR code that could add a Vcal event with:
Start date and time: as of the date and time the code is scanned
End date and time: exactly xx weeks after the start date (say 2 weeks)

Comment: Please provide more info, because it's not clear what you want.

Comment: Basically i want a qr code that once scanned with my iphone, add an event in the calendar starting on whatever day i scanned the qr and ending 2 weeks after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iCalendar, you can specify a duration inside a VEVENT with the DURATION property. (See section 4.3.6 of [RFC 2445](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt).) You can use this instead of DTEND. The syntax is a little hard to explain; you can see it in the RFC. `DURATION:PT1H30M` means 1 hour, 30 minutes. `DURATION:P2W` means two weeks.

So, you can just add this to the `VEVENT` you were already going to encode in a QR code.

Of course, whether a reader reads it correctly is another story. I can tell you that [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing) does not read `DURATION`. Because I wrote it and I have just learned that `DURATION` exists. I will add it as a to-do to parse correctly.

Comment: PS I just added this into the project. For 2 weeks, use "DURATION:P2W"

Comment: Be more specific? Like I said, I've no idea if the reader you have would interpret it, but the above is entirely correct to *encode* your intent.

Comment: I am using QRreader app on iphone. I have the following encoding: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=350x350&chl=BEGIN%3AVEVENT%0D%0D%0ASUMMARY%3ATEST2%0D%0ADURATION%3AP2W%0ADESCRIPTION%3ATEST2%0D%0AEND%3AvEVENT%0D%0A  but when i read it it just creates an event starting now and ending tomorrow...

Comment: Yes, it doesn't support it I suppose. Even Barcode Scanner doesn't, but will in the next version. You're encoding it correctly though. For compatibility I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: ok too bad for me then...but when  you say " for compaitibilty i wouldn t recommend this", what do you mean? So there is no way i encode this function in a QR code and it becomes readable?